# Burning the Arduino bootloader without an extra Arduino board

Tags: bootloader

Is there any way to burn the Arduino bootloader on a standalone Atmega328 (internal clock 8MHz) from the Arduino official website without using an extra Arduino board to burn the bootloader?

I mean, is it possible to burn the bootloader on the Arduino and then remove the ATmega chip from the Arduino board and use it in a breadboard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to go the route of a dedicated programmer, you could try ArduinoISP where you can program an Arduino board (with a Mega on it) to be a programmer for another AVR device (e.g. another Mega). The instructions can be found at https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP and allows you to do something like this:

[image: arduinoisp]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use an ISP programmer. I personally use [Atmel ICE](http://www.atmel.com/tools/atatmel-ice.aspx), [Arduinos as ISP](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) and [USBasp](http://www.fischl.de/usbasp/).

AVRISP is another popular option:

[image]

This tutorial might be useful: [Sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/installing-an-arduino-bootloader).

Comment: so it's not possible to burn the bootloader on the ATMega using the arduino board itself (conectet to the pc via USB) and then remove the MCU and use it standalone?

Comment: Not using the board itself. (It could be possible if you modified the USB>Serial Atmega to become some sort of USBtinyISP, cut and rewired a bunch of stuff, but it wouldn't be practical at all and you'd still need a programmer to reprogram it anyway). So you need a programmer at some point.